# Swing: Programmatically select a text

Tags: java, swing, textarea, selection

I have a very simple Swing GUI with just a JTetxtArea. I am trying to programmatically select a part of text using:

```
textArea.select(startSelection,endSelection);
```

This work. However as soon as I add some other components to the GUI I do not see selection anymore

```
frame.getContentPane().add(button);     
frame.getContentPane().add(textArea);
textArea.select(startSelection,endSelection);
```

I suspect that during layouting the gui, some event causes the text to be deselected. Am I right? And could anybody suggest a solution?

My goal is to have a program which displays a text, and allows the user to input start and end selection position, and a selection appears between these two position. Thank you.

Comment: can't you just make sure that the textArea.select is fired *after* the frame has been laid out?

Comment: actually, I gave a simplified example. I have subclassed a GUI component, and the call to select() occurs inside it. How do I know when the frame is laid out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text selection only shows when the text component has focus.

Text components also support "highlighting" by using the getHighlighter().addHighlight() method. In this case the highlighting remains whether the component has focus or not.

If you need more help post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If what you really want is just a selection, not highlight (which behaves differently), you can use `JTextComponent.getCaret().setSelectionVisible(true)`.